# Calling AJAX methods in parallel increases server response time?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

I came across a piece of code where the methods where being called as callbacks

```
function a()
{
  $.get("/Controller/Action", function (data) {
    b();
}
}

function b()
{
  $.get("/Controller/Action", function (data) {
    c();
}
}
```

There network calls
[image: As callbacks]

Now instead of calling them as callbacks, I made them to be called together concurrently

```
a();
b();
c();
```

I expected improvement but I see a weird thing
[image]

Why would the server response time increase? I have tested many times. I never really get the response time like I would get using the first way.

Comment: I have tested it and it shows the same results.
there was no huge difference between the two solutions
could you share the backend code.